Is it better to have one main class for the stage and scenes in JavaFX?
I had written a command line-based Java application game a while ago, and now that I've got more programming experience I was attempting to re-make it in JavaFX for a more user-friendly feel (buttons instead of typing in actions/choices, a text box instead of System.out.println, clicking a 'next' button instead of having a prompt that says '(Press enter to continue...)' in the command line, etc.)
I am trying to implement best practices for this, and so I have a main class:
public class MoUD_FX extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
    
        var labelText = new Label(""); 
        
        var box = new VBox(labelText); 
        
        var mainMenu = new Scene(box, 600, 400); // just here to populate a sample screen
        stage.setScene(mainMenu);
        stage.show(); 

        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
    
}

Now I have other classes to handle the logic of the game, but in the original they were all written back then when all I would do to have user interaction was to use System.in and System.out, for example:
public class Player {
    
    public static void startAbility() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean correctInput = false;
        while (correctInput == false) {
            System.out.println("Select your starting stat loadout by entering one of these names: ");
            System.out.println("Heroic: stats are balanced and well-rounded.");
            System.out.println("Warlike: evasive, magic, and defensive skills are replaced with warrior-like stats.");
            System.out.println("Brutal: most stats lowered in exchange for massive health and powerful attack.");
            System.out.println("Stealthy: more focused on dodging and defending than brute force.");
            System.out.println("Magical: mana is mostly focused on.");
            System.out.println("Spiritual: lowered attack, defence, and health to compensate for the heightened mana.");
            System.out.println("Safe: with increased health, concentration, and evasion for a less risky fight.");
            System.out.println("Enter a class: ");
            String selector = input.next();

// ... rest of class
}

Clearly this could've been better written had I known more back then, but this is where I am and it's still easier than re-writing everything from scratch.
My question is, what would be the best programming practice for implementing the overall flow/structure of this application for this?
Is it better to have just my main class be the only one that extends Application, sets the Scene, and sets the stage to show, and have my other classes just edit a portion of it? Like for example to change the text, it would be along the lines of:
public class MoUD_FX extends Application {
    private static String output;
    
    public static void setLabel(String change) {
        output = change;
    }
//...

And then replace the System.out.println() calls in the other classes to
MoUD_FX.setLabel("[Text]")

Or should I have each class have their own scene or stage and edit it there, in which case what would I need to pass to those classes? For example:
public class Player {
    
    public static void startAbility() {
        Stage mainStage = MoUD_FX.getStage();
//...

I could just find a way to redirect System.out to a GUI text box, but I'm also curious about general programming practice when it comes to JavaFX, for future notes.
Note: I am not using Maven; just NetBeans IDE-generated Ant build script, and I have that currently working; I do not need to use scene builder, I'm fine with the basics in this case

Your question is very broad, but this Swing example show one approach, while this Q&A illustrates converting to JavaFX.

"Is it better to have just my main class be the only one that extends Application" -- You should only have one class extend Application in a JavaFX application. However, that does not preclude the use of multiple windows or even multiple scenes with a single window. Though if you use a single window then I recommend also using a single scene. Cases where changing the scene couldn't instead be implemented by modifying the nodes in said scene are rare.

Note that all assumes a pure GUI application. But it kind of sounds like you are trying to add GUI functionality to an existing CLI application. Mixing a GUI with a CLI is not a great idea. Something that may provide a better learning experience is to try and refactor the game logic out of your existing CLI application so that it can be used as the backend of both your CLI application and your GUI application.

"Now I have other classes to handle the logic of the game, but in the original they were all written back then when all I would do to have user interaction was to use System.in and System.out . . . it's still easier than re-writing everything from scratch." -> oh, but is it?  and does it give the best graphical user experience? You shall see ;-)

This is a software engineering question, not a StackOverflow question, but I'll answer it here anyway.
It is an opinionated answer as many design questions are.  But, in this case, the opinion and consensus on this is pretty clear: Keep your Application class as lightweight as possible.
Practice separations of concerns:

Separation of concerns is a design principle for separating a computer program into distinct sections. Each section addresses a separate concern, a set of information that affects the code of a computer program.

For trivial programs (like many example JavaFX applications on StackOverflow), it is convenient to have all the code in a single application class.
However, for anything non-trivial (and that would include the application you describe in your question), it is better to apply separation of concerns and create additional structure for the code.
The concerns (you can also call them responsibilities) of a JavaFX Application are well-defined in the Javadoc.  The main responsibility is to implement the Application lifecycle.  You should not add anything to your Application implementation that does anything outside of the core responsibility for the Application (implementing the lifecycle).
For simple applications such as that described in your question, you only need to provide an implementation for the start method, and a main method entry point.
public class GameApp extends Application {
    private final Game game = new Game();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage(new Scene(game.getUI()));
        stage();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

Then you define separate classes for handling game logic, representing game state, and handling the game UI.
public class Game {
    // GameModel holds JavaFX properties modeling the app state.
    private GameModel model;  
    // GameUI is a parent node for displaying the app UI.
    private GameUI gameUI;

    public Game() {
         // init the model
         // init the UI
         // wire the UI and model together
    }

    public GameUI getUI() {
        return gameUI;
    }
}

There are numerous advantages to this (this is just a sample):

An Application class already has well-defined responsibilities which are plenty for it, you don't need to complicate it further by adding your own responsibilities to it.
If you share an Application class just to get access to your game logic or UI, you expose other details of the Application (e.g. ability to get host services, set user agent stylesheets, invoke lifecycle methods, etc), that the classes that want to interact with the game logic or UI just don't need to know.  So you end up with poor encapsulation.
You have complete control over the lifecycle of objects you create, but you don't have that for the Application class which can only have one instance and has a lifecycle maintained by the JavaFX system.

For instance let's say you wanted to have a replay option.  If the game is defined by an object you control, then all you need do is throw the old game instance away and create a new one.  But if the game were defined in an application that would be difficult because there can only be one application instance.


You can separate UI and game logic.  If everything in your Application glass, the UI and game logic are all mixed in together with the application lifecycle handling.  Especially when you add event handling into the mix, it quickly becomes unwieldy.
You can test your game logic separately using unit tests, which you can't do for code in an Application class.
If you want to share the application with other objects, it is difficult to do so because there is only one instance of the application, so getting clean access to it without just adding static methods or state is problematic.

With a separated structure, the game UI can be defined in either Java code or FXML or even have the implementation switched between the two without having to ever modify your Application class.
Although not necessary, I recommend following MVC principles for handling the application state and the representation of that in the UI.  An example is in:

Applying MVC With JavaFx

Some things you should not do:

Define lots of static methods (such as in the example in your question).
Create a lot of static state.
Put all of your logic in your Application class.

I won't explain all of the reasons why you should not do these things, but experience has shown for multiple developers that such approaches often cause issues down the line.
